Calculating confidence intervals for proportion data (multiple data points)
Folks -
I am looking for a way to calculate a confidence interval (e.g. 95%) or other metric of variability for a data series (a sample of multiple data points) in which the data are all proportions (i.e., each datum is between zero and one). I assume this method is different from calculating a standard CI for data that are continuous, can be any numeric value, etc. Note that I am not asking for CI estimation for a single proportion (e.g., Clopper-Pearson method). R code or Excel formula would be helpful. Can't seem to find this in any basic textbook. Thanks.
Example data set:
0.12, 0.24, 0.93, 0.56, 0.02

You are looking for a CI for what quantity exactly?

Confidence interval for the mean.

You can use fractional response regression. There are probit, logit, and heteroscedastic probit versions. With no covariates, they should all be equivalent. This assumes you have considerably more than 5 data points since it relies on asymptotics.
The fractional logit can be implemented with a binomial family GLM model with a logit link, heteroskedastic variance-covariance matrix, and no covariates (i.e., an intercept-only model). Alternatively, you can use a quasibinomial family and that will adjust the SEs directly. The second approach is simpler and is shown below. The inverse logit of the intercept will give you the expected proportion and the inverse logit of intercept’s 95% CI will give the appropriate confidence interval on the proportion [0,1] scale.
Here's an R example for this data:
> # Install the 'emmeans' package (uncomment if not already installed)
> # install.packages("emmeans")
> 
> # Load the 'emmeans' library
> library(emmeans)
> 
> # Create the data frame (or else import CSV)
> data <- data.frame(prop = c(0.12, 0.24, 0.93, 0.56, 0.02))
> 
> # Fit the fractional logit model using quasibinomial family
> flog <- glm(prop ~ 1, family = "quasibinomial", data = data)
> 
> # Display a summary of the fitted model
> summary(flog)

Call:
glm(formula = prop ~ 1, family = "quasibinomial", data = data)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  -0.5151     0.7093  -0.726    0.508

(Dispersion parameter for quasibinomial family taken to be 0.5889348)

    Null deviance: 2.6993  on 4  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 2.6993  on 4  degrees of freedom
AIC: NA

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 3

> 
> # Compute estimated marginal means and transform them to the response scale
> emmeans(flog, ~1, type = "response")
 1        prob    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 overall 0.374 0.166 Inf      0.13     0.706

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the logit scale 
> 
> 
> # Calculate the CI from GLM Coefficients)
> # Define the inverse logit function
> inv_logit <- function(x) {
+   exp(x) / (1 + exp(x))
+ }
> 
> # Calculate the lower bound of the confidence interval
> inv_logit(-0.5151 - 1.96 * 0.7093)
[1] 0.1295066
> 
> # Calculate the upper bound of the confidence interval
> inv_logit(-0.5151 + 1.96 * 0.7093)
[1] 0.7058116

Here the 95% CI is [0.13, 0.706]. With more than 5 data points, you should get something much tighter.

Thank you dimitriy. May I ask you the steps by which you arrived at the CI for the example data (e.g., R code)? I find examples extremely helpful as I am pretty novice with R and am not quite sure how to generate expected values. Many thanks.

@AlexH Added R code. Let me know if you have any questions.

Code works for me - very helpful. Thanks again for your assistance.

@AlexH If this solves your problem, please select it as the answer!

Sorry - new to Cross Validated. Can you tell me how to select it as the answer?

@AlexH The checkmark on the left.

For a complete answer, could you please explain why bivariate regression applies when there is only a single variable.

@rolando2 See my edits. This is really a regression of the proportion on a pseudo-variable of consisting of all ones, which allows you to easily calculate the mean in any GLM.
